# Call UIAlertView delegate method with parameter?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton, uialertview

I've added a button on cell of my table view like this-

```
UIButton* checkBoxBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[checkBoxBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check_normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [checkBoxBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(checkBoxAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    checkBoxBtn.tag = indexPath.row;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:checkBoxBtn];
```

and this is my checkBoxAction

```
-(void) checkBoxAction: (UIButton *)sender
{
    NSInteger i =sender.tag + 1;
    float perc = (i*100/18.0);
    NSLog(@"%.2f",perc);
    NSString* percentageStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%3.2f%%(%d out of 18)",perc, i];
    barTitle.text = percentageStr;
    barFGImage.hidden = NO;
    if (perc == 100.00) {
        [barFGImage setFrame:CGRectMake(barFGImage.frame.origin.x, barFGImage.frame.origin.y, 276.0, barFGImage.frame.size.height)];
    }
    else
    [barFGImage setFrame:CGRectMake(barFGImage.frame.origin.x, barFGImage.frame.origin.y, 280*perc/100, barFGImage.frame.size.height)];
    [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check_select.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    sender.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
}
```

And every thing OK for now, but i want to show an alert when user press `checkBoxBtn` and if user press OK then the `checkBoxAction` should called.I know we have `UIAlertView` delegate method

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

But problem is that how to get checkBoxBtn in it?

**EDIT:** It is OK with Midhun MP's answer, but i want one more thing- in my cell i have three labels and a button [image: like this screen shot], with the click on check box i want to change label 'Due in 6 days' along with other stuff that we done in my `checkBoxAction` method
Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: I've edited question please check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For achieving this you need to implement the `- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex` delegate method.

You can do it like:

Declare a UIButton instance in .h
like:

```
UIButton *button;
```

Change the button adding method like:

```
UIButton* checkBoxBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[checkBoxBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check_normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[checkBoxBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(showAlert:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
checkBoxBtn.tag = indexPath.row;
[cell.contentView addSubview:checkBoxBtn];


 - (void) showAlert:(id)sender
{
   button = (UIButton *)sender
   UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: @"Cancel"];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
   if(buttonIndex == 0)
   {
      [self checkBoxAction:button];
   }
}
```

For getting the label:

Add a tag to the label in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` like:

```
statusText.tag = 7;
[cell.contentView addSubview:statusText];
```

And you can get the label using the following code:

```
UILabel *tempLabel = (UIlabel *)[[button superview] viewWithTag:7];
tempLabel.text = @"Midhun";
```

Comment: I also have a label on cell and i want to access it like we do button, so have to send another parameter? CAn you please explain?

Comment: sorry again error- Property view not found on object of type UIButton

Comment: Change the loop:
for(UIView *view in [[[button superview] superview] subviews])

Comment: I've edited question please check, i can't access my label yet

Comment: @Blios: if you have teamviewer I can help, or come in chat

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19990/discussion-between-blios-and-midhun-mp)